# Trying to Find short method for this equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find out more methods to solve this equation in shortly

$24/(x-y) +36/(x+y) =6$

$36/(x-y)+24/(x+y) = 13/2$

I solved it mutiplying both equations and make it same then solved it but big method tike consuming.

Comment: If the denominators are $x+y$ and similar, maybe try the variable change $u = \frac{1}{x+y}$ and likewise for $v.$

Comment: The way that you have the equation written out is probably not what you mean. Currently, the second equation is
$$
\frac {36}x - y + \frac {24}x + y = \frac {13}2,
$$
but I suspect you mean
$$
\frac {36}{x - y} + \frac {24}{x + y} = \frac {13}2.
$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can rewrite the two equations as $f=g=0$ with two polynomials $f,g$ in $x$ and $y$, whose resultant $Res(f,g,y)=0$ yields $x(10-x)=0$. Of course $x\neq 0$, so that $x=10$ and hence $y=2$.

Comment: Did you delete the comments? Ohh no i was trying to learn it i can't see anything now. I was reading Wikipedia

Comment: Still hard to understand. I put polynomial cofficient into determinant form. I don't know why they choose d=3 and e=2 in wikipedia example. It's not clear yet. How did you get x10-x) form. Please explain sir

Answer (score 1):

If you replace $\frac{12}{x-y}$ by $A$ and replace $\frac{12}{x+y}$ by $B$ then you obtain the much easier equations:
$$2A+3B=6,3A+2B=\frac{13}{2}$$
These have solution
$$A=\frac{3}{2},B=1$$
Then  $$x-y=\frac{12}{A}=8$$ $$x+y=\frac{12}{B}=12$$
And the solution is $x=10,y=2$.

Comment: Yeah this method seems more interesting thanks

Comment: Yes, it can quite often be useful to replace complicated looking expressions by single letters

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't mean that Dietrich and i am not saying your answer is uninteresting. Your answer is also interesting and very very short but i am learning it right now. I am willing to learn new methods. Still reading Wikipedia and trying to use it for my equation. Thanks for this new method too. I'll not leave it untill I learn it properly 